# PHP mail() not working when receiving an ajax POST request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, email

I have setup a form that uses jQuery ajax to send a POST request to an external php file, which then sends the email. I am getting a 200 status code but not receiving the email.

Here is the jQuery:

```
var ajaxSend = function(dataObj) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'send.php',
            data: dataObj,
            success: function() {console.log('Ajax Success!');}, 
            error: function() {console.log('Ajax Error!');},
            statusCode: {
                200: function() {console.log('200 Everything ok!');},
                400: function() {console.log('400 Bad request');},
                403: function() {console.log('403 Forbidden');},
                500: function() {console.log('500  Server error');}
            }
        });
}


    $('.contact-form input[type="submit"]').click(function(e) {

        if($('form')[0].checkValidity()) { //checks if insetred value meets the HTML5 required attribute
            e.preventDefault();
            var dataObj = {
                name:  $.trim($('.contact-form input[type="text"]').val()),
                email:  $.trim($('.contact-form input[type="email"]').val()),
                message:  $.trim($('.contact-form textarea').val())
            };

            ajaxSend(dataObj);

        } else { console.log("Invalid form"); }
    });
```

Here is the php file:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $to_email = "myemail@gmail.com";
    $data = json_decode($_POST['dataObj']);    

    $subject = 'Email subject';
    $headers = 'From: '.$data['email'];
    $message  = 'Name: '.$data['name'].' \n';
    $message .= 'Email: '.$data['email'].' \n\n';
    $message .= 'Message:\n'.$data['message'].' \n';
    if (mail($to_email, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        http_response_code(200);
    } else {
        http_response_code(500);
    }

} else {
    http_response_code(403);
}
```

The web hosting is windows, I've tryed using a POST request without and it works just fine, i receive the email. I don't think it's a php.ini problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first problem is that you are using `$_POST['dataObj']` on the server side while the data is only available right in `$_POST` (dataObj is a javascript variable name that won't be passed on to the server). You can get the email for example by reading `$_POST['email']`. Try to change your send.php to this:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $to_email = "myemail@gmail.com"; 

  $subject = 'Email subject';
  $headers = 'From: '.$_POST['email'];
  $message  = 'Name: '.$_POST['name'].' \n';
  $message .= 'Email: '.$_POST['email'].' \n\n';
  $message .= 'Message:\n'.$_POST['message'].' \n';
  if (mail($to_email, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    http_response_code(200);
  } else {
    http_response_code(500);
  }

} else {
  http_response_code(403);
}
```

Note: it's not safe to use $_POST directly in the $headers-variable without some kind of escaping. An attacker can set additional parameters if you leave it like that. Google on that before using it on production.

It might be that something in the sending process is blocking mails with malformed headers more easily than your linux setup, if you receive an 200. 
However you should have gotten an misformed email with the php code you provided, is that correct? Answer to this post in case the error still occurs afterwards.

Comment: Yes! It was an error with $data and the json_decode() function, didn't know  you could access the post data just the normal way.

Comment: I will, also can you elaborate what do you mean by escaping? I've noticed the \n didn't render and it didn't go on next line as expected

Comment: Try to use $message .= 'some text'.PHP_EOL to use linebreaks. I typically use \r\n in my mails but the PHP_EOL constant should do better. You can read about the escaping thingy at http://mattgeri.com/2012/01/escaping-input-to-the-php-mail-function/